# Seconds past J2000

Tags: python, datetime, time

I would like to convert a UTC date time to seconds past J2000 epoch.

Which is January 1, 2000 at 12:00 TT.

The prefix "J" indicates that it is a Julian epoch.

Probably makes sense to use [time module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), but not clear how.

TT specifier (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what's tt?

Comment: How is the date formatted, and will you need to do timezone conversions with it? The `datetime` module, and in particular `timedelta` objects, might be helpful.

Comment: You can use subtraction on two datetime objects to get a "timedelta" object. For example `(t.now() - t).seconds` will give you the number of seconds from time `t` to now.

Comment: TT specifier (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier)

Comment: What's the format of the date you're trying to convert?

Comment: I want to convert UTC time to J2000

Comment: When is J2000 in terms of the Gregorian calendar in use today?

Comment: Global Navigation Satellite System data